# ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 not working on hls input

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

Im running this command to re-stream an hls to my rtmp server.

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -fflags +igndts -hide_banner -re -i playlist_main2_c.m3u8 -c copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp:****** -loglevel verbose`

Looks like **-stream_loop -1** is not taking effect, the error will display after playing the last .ts file

**[AVIOContext @ 0x7f8c42705080] Statistics: 362088 bytes read, 0 seeks296.7kbits/s speed=1.01x
Seek to start failed.
playlist_main2_c.m3u8: Operation not permitted**

Comment: Whats the output of `ffmpeg -version`?

Comment: ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
....

Comment: Just for testing, try streaming to FFplay: `ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -stream_loop -1 -fflags +igndts -hide_banner -re -i playlist_main2_c.m3u8 -c copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize pipe: | ffplay pipe:`.

Comment: Still got error ```Seek to start failed. playlist_main2_c.m3u8: Operation not permitted```. Upon my investigation looks like the problem is on my playlist files (.ts), not an expert on ffmpeg but maybe it has something to do with the encoding. Im thinking if theres a way to fix this by adding additional flags. Heres the link of the playlist file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1szArjypGDVZgzV5O3KyI5GtUSGZTo_J3/view?usp=sharing